# Java Classloading

Tags: java, classloader

I have a same class belonging to 2 different packages.

```
package x1.y1.Class
packgage x2.y2.Class
```

Is it possible that if I am invoking a `x1.y1.Class` via classloader, `x2.y2.Class` loads instead?

Comment: Do you mean accidentally? Or is this what you're *trying* to achieve?

Comment: yups.. accidentally.. is ther any probability

Comment: No.. Unless you are doing it wrong it won't happen.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply said, **no** (unless you unintentionally load the wrong one).

Classes are loaded by their fully-qualified class-name, which includes the package (e.g. `x1.y1.Class`)

Answer (score 4):

No, it can't happen, for two reasons:

- The classloader *finds* the class by package, by looking in the right place
- Even if you accidentally put a class in the wrong place, the class file itself includes the package name, and this is checked during class loading.

I've just tried doing this deliberately, replacing `p1/Foo.class` with the file for class `p2.Foo`, and received the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: p1/Foo (wrong name: p2/Foo)
```

If you *wanted* to do this, you'd need a classloader which deliberately looked in the wrong location, and then modified the bytecode it loaded.